# Paypal 3rd party Shopping Cart integration doesnot return form values

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am facing a problem in paypal 3rd party shopping cart integration. After the sucessfull payment, it doesnot get back values from paypal. I am using the following code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Item Name 3">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="3.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="Item Name 4">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="4.00">
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/paypal_multiple.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return'value='http://localhost/paypal_multiple.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='custom' value='customer@gmail.com'>
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://localhost/paypal_multiple.php'>
<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching other questions in SO, I found that below two fields were missing.It's working fine now.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
```

Comment: what was the solution?